# Fastest way to zero out a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that I want to clear and reset to 0 values. I know how to clear a vector (1D array) using `Array.Clear()` but I don't know the best way to clear a 2D matrix.

```
double D = new double[10];  
Array.Clear(D, 0, D.Length);
```

How does one clear a 2D N x M array

```
double D[,] = new double[N,M];
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`Array.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx) works with multidimensional arrays, too:

```
double[,] D = new double[M,N];
Array.Clear(D, 0, D.Length);
```

Note, there's no need to compute the length yourself, since the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) property returns the total number of elements, regardless of the number of dimensions:

> A 32-bit integer that represents the total number of elements in all the dimensions of the Array; zero if there are no elements in the array.

Comment: `((IList)D).Clear()` is equivalent to `Array.Clear(D, 0, D.Length)` and _might_ be preferable, if only because using `Length` to clear a rectangular array seems odd at first glance.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I'd never thought about using it like that because to me `IList.Clear` means 'remove all elements', not 'set all elements to default', but yes that seems to work just fine.

Comment: Will D.Length be the same as M*N?

Comment: @PBrenek Yes. Or more generally, it's the product of all the dimensions of an array.

Comment: @p.s.w.g  so does ((IList)D).Clear() actually set the values to default as well?

Comment: @GelatinFox Yes, `IList.Clear()` is implemented in the `Array` class as `Array.Clear(this, 0, this.Length);`. This has the effect of setting each element of the array to the default value of that type: `0` for `int`'s and `double`'s, `null` for reference types.

Comment: If you go through the contents of a multidimensional array in debug mode you'll see it also simply lists them as one list ([0,0] to [0,x] then [1,0] to [1,x] etc), and not as a collection of sub-arrays. In reality these things are completely linear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method, but you may have to calculate your real `length` parameter value:

```
double D[,] = new double[N,M];
Array.Clear(D, 0, M*N);
```

I would use `M*N` because it's more readable, and I don't know what `Length` property returns for 2-dimmentional array.

Answer (score -1):

Just reallocate it.

```
double D[,] = new double[N,M];
```

creates a empty 2D array.

Comment: I'm actually for this. While it does result in a *new* Array, which may or may not fit into the existing approach (and does take some leeway with the question), only benchmarks can indicate if one approach is appreciably more suitable than another.

Comment: Well, the memory allocator will *always* zero the array immediately after grabbing memory, so this will always be slower.  Not to mention the GC pressure.